# hide div in dynamic page in codeingnater

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

i have codeignater website http://zafatalmasa.net/  it was build in codeignater
its for wedding songs   and there is aapge that load  different sections  of songs from database
i want to remove order button from just one page

```
<div class="squaredOne">
    <input type="checkbox" 
           id="squaredOne_<?php echo $item->id; ?>" 
           name="album[]" class="select_zafa_item" 
           value="<?php echo $item->id; ?>" />
    <label for="squaredOne_<?php echo $item->id; ?>"></label>
</div>
```

and i don't want to remove it from other page can i remove it pased on url from php or js ?
the page url :  http://zafatalmasa.net/Q-%D8%AA%D9%86%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%B0%D9%86%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B5%D8%B1%D9%8A-%D9%85%D8%B9-%D9%83%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%8A%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%AA%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B3%D9%85

Comment: can you post your jquery code, please

Answer (score 0):

You can use `current_url()` helper function:

```
<?php if (current_url() !== 'what-ever-you-need') : ?>
    <div class="squaredOne"  >
        <input type="checkbox" 
               id="squaredOne_<?php echo $item->id; ?>" 
               name="album[]" class="select_zafa_item" 
               value="<?php echo $item->id; ?>" />
        <label for="squaredOne_<?php echo $item->id; ?>"></label>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a specific segment  of the URL from this

```
$pageName = $this->uri->segment(1);
if($pageName!="Your page name"){
  //...
}
```